# Perform Subtraction in Moment Js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to subtract the **duration** value from the **end** value. How can I do that with moment.js? I am currently getting the error `not valid ISO-8601 date format`.

```
let start = 1977
let end = 1985
let duration = moment(start.toString()).unix() - moment(end.toString()).unix();
let newvalue = = moment(end.toString()).unix() - moment(duration.toString()).unix();
```

The calculation I have for duration works, so I thought to replicate it for **newvalue**, but that doesn't work. Am I missing anything? It must be in ISO-8601 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.add` or `.subtract` methods to add/subtract a duration.

Not your question, but I would expect the duration to be end-start, not start-end.

Here is how it could work:

```js
let start = 1977
let end = 1985
let duration = moment(end.toString()).unix() - moment(start.toString()).unix();
let newvalue = moment(end.toString()).subtract(duration, "second");

console.log(newvalue.toString()); // Full date string 
console.log(newvalue.year()); // 1977
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Take note of the message from the authors of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

> we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward

Comment: thank you. I am getting a ```.subtract is not a function```. Also, is there a way for me to get just the 1977 as the newValue and not the whole format?

Comment: Strange, as you can see, when you run this snippet, it runs without error. Sure, you can get the year of a date by chaining the `.year()` method (added to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to subtract the small value from the large one.
   Here in your case, you should `subtract start from the end`
2. You get the duration value in unix, so you don't need to do it again

```js
let start = 1977
let end = 1985
let duration = moment(end.toString()).unix() - moment(start.toString()).unix();
let newvalue = moment(end.toString()).unix() - duration;
console.log(duration);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`duration` should already represent a duration in seconds, so you can just subtract that from `moment(end.toString()).unix()` (which represents the number of seconds since the Unix epoch):

```
let newvalue = moment(end.toString()).unix() - duration;
```

Keep in mind that in your code you are subtracting the `end` value from the `start` value, which is negative since `start < end`. I don't think this was intended, so you could either use `Math.abs()` or subtract `end` from `start`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using `moment.duration()` and `diff()`.

You can get the duration in days using `asDays()` or in hours using `asHours()`.

Please check snippet below :

```js
let start = 1977
let end = 1985
let duration = moment.duration(moment(end.toString()).diff(moment(start.toString())));
console.log(duration.asDays())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```